# img by changing it's src and is drawn by a dynamically provided source (mysql and php) with a Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have these scripts:

```
<?
/*//Disable error reporting
error_reporting(0);
*/
//Report runtime errors
//error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

//Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//end of error reporting

?>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').on('change', function(e){
    var selected_value = $(this).val();
    var option_data = $(this).children('option[value="'+selected_value+'"]');

    // get data values
    var visanumber = option_data.data('visanumber');
    var idnumber = option_data.data('idnumber');
    var statusapp = option_data.data('statusapp');
    var subdate = option_data.data('subdate');
    // the photo
    var accntvisaphotopath = option_data.data('accntvisaphotopath');
    if(accntvisaphotopath == 'data-passport=') {
        $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('img.accntVisaPhotoPath').attr('src', 'accntvisaphotopath');
        $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('img.passportPath').attr('src', 'passportpath');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('img.passportPath').attr('src', 'passportpath');
        $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('img.accntVisaPhotoPath').attr('src', 'accntvisaphotopath');
    }
    // set the values
    $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('span.visanumber').text(visanumber);
    $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('span.idnumber').text(idnumber);
    $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('span.statusapp').text(statusapp);
    $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('span.subdate').text(subdate);
     });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?

 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxxx","xxxx");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}    
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM visa ORDER BY idvisa");

?>
<div align="center">
<form name="contractInfo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<table border="1px" width="700">
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="7"><b>Email:</b><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th> <div align="center">&nbsp;Applicant Name&nbsp;</div></th>
    <th> <div align="center">Visa Number</div></th>
    <th> <div align="center">ID Number </div></th>
    <th> <div align="center">Employment Status</div></th>
    <th> <div align="center">&nbsp;Visa&nbsp;</div></th>
    <th> <div align="center">&nbsp;Passport&nbsp;</div></th>
    <th> <div align="center"><font color="red">Elapse</div></th>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select>
<? echo "<option value=\"\">Select Person:</option>";?><br>
<? while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value=".$row['idvisa']." data-visanumber=".$row['visanumber']." data-idnumber=".$row['idnumber']." data-statusapp='{$row['statusapp']}' data-accntVisaPhotoPath=".$row['accntVisaPhotoPath']." data-passport=".$row['passportPath']." data-subdate='{$row['subdate']}'>".$row['fName']." ".$row['lName']."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
<?//Additional var
//Time
$today = date("Y/m/d G:i:s");
$date= $row["subdate"];
$days = strtotime($today) - strtotime($date);

//End Time
?>
</td>
<td><span class="visanumber"></span></td>
<td><span class="idnumber"></span></td> 
<td><span class="statusapp"></span></td>    
<td align="center"><img class="accntVisaPhotoPath" height="50" width="50"></img></td>   
<td align="center"><img class="passportPath" height="50" width="50"></img></td>
<td><span class="subdate"></span></td>
</span>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select>
<? 
mysqli_data_seek( $result, 0 );
echo "<option value=\"\">Select Person:</option>";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value=".$row['idvisa']." data-visanumber=".$row['visanumber']." data-idnumber=".$row['idnumber']." data-statusapp='{$row['statusapp']}' data-accntVisaPhotoPath=".$row['accntVisaPhotoPath']." data-passport=".$row['passportPath']." data-subdate='{$row['subdate']}'>".$row['fName']." ".$row['lName']."</option>";
}   
?>
</td>
<td><span class="visanumber"></span></td>
<td><span class="idnumber"></span></td> 
<td><span class="statusapp"></span></td>    
<td align="center"><img class="accntVisaPhotoPath" height="50" width="50"></img></td>   
<td align="center"><img class="passportPath" height="50" width="50"></img></td>
<td><span class="subdate"></span></td>
</span>
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
    <input type="button" name="cancelvalue" value="CANCEL" onClick="self.close()"> 
    <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Clear" height="14"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" height="14">
<br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and may aim is to change it's src

```
<td align="center"><img class="accntVisaPhotoPath" height="50" width="50"></img></td>   
<td align="center"><img class="passportPath" height="50" width="50"></img></td>
```

I have tried to search in here but it seems I am too dumb in revising what I have found. I know, it is simple but I am new in handling custom data attributes and then have the Javascript populate it all BUT the image has caught me unprepared.

And my [L A B](http://www.lab.workforceint.com/contract.php) is here.

Comment: what will happen when the select box is changed?

Comment: It will populate the entire row and then display the images.

Comment: What's PHP got to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest use classes in this case, don't use ID because it will have multiple rows.

```
<td><span class="visanumber"></span></td>
<td><span class="idnumber"></span></td>    
<td><span class="statusapp"></span></td>   
<td align="center"><img class="accntVisaPhotoPath" height="50" width="50"></td>    
<td align="center"><img class="passport" height="50" width="50"></td>
<td><span class="subdate"></span></td>
```

Then, just target that option based on the value you selected. Then extract those data attributes values according to selection.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').on('change', function(e){
    var selected_value = $(this).val();
    var option_data = $(this).children('option[value="'+selected_value+'"]');

    // get data values
    var visanumber = option_data.data('visanumber');
    var idnumber = option_data.data('idnumber');
    var statusapp = option_data.data('statusapp');
    var subdate = option_data.data('subdate');

    // the photo
    var accntVisaPhotoPath = option_data.data('accntvisaphotopath');
    $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('img.accntVisaPhotoPath').attr('src', accntVisaPhotoPath);

    var passportPath = option_data.data('passportpath');
    $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('img.passportPath').attr('src', passportPath);

    // set the values
    $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('span.visanumber').text(visanumber);
    $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('span.idnumber').text(idnumber);
    $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('span.statusapp').text(statusapp);
    $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('span.subdate').text(subdate);
    });
 });
 </script>
```

Of course the path of the images is up to you since no PHP codes are found in your question, this is just an example.

Here is a working demo:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/GhH6Yh

thanks

Comment: I have corrected some of the vars but then, I have these error at the console: GET http://www.lab.workforceint.com/accntVisaPhotoPath 500 (Internal Server Error) accntVisaPhotoPath:1
GET http://www.lab.workforceint.com/passportPath 500 (Internal Server Error) .  I am looking for the contents. Hmmm

Comment: I have remove some ' ' on .attr('src', passportPath); it is my fault.  But then, there is no src at [http://www.lab.workforceint.com/contract.php](http://www.lab.workforceint.com/contract.php)

Comment: @Jong thats what i told last time, you need to properly echo those values, if you look closely, you'll see the data attribute value is malformed there is no value. properly echo the values of `$row`. are you sure there is values in the `$row['accntVisaPhotoPath']`?

Comment: I have this as echo " echo "<option value=".$row['idvisa']." data-visanumber=".$row['visanumber']." data-idnumber=".$row['idnumber']." data-statusapp="$row['statusapp']" data-accntVisaPhotoPath=".$row['accntVisaPhotoPath']." data-passportPath=".$row['passportPath']." data-subdate="$row['subdate']">".$row['fName']." ".$row['lName']."</option>";
 But the "statusapp" got chopped off.  Instead of "For Selection" it only displays "For" .. :(

Comment: @Jong tsk my goodness what up with this bug, the chatroom should work for you now, damn, anyways use `data-statusapp='".$row['statusapp']."'` mind the quotes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65030/discussion-between-jong-and-ghost).

Answer (score 0):

Your get Image Path should return a image to show up, try this:

```
function getImagePath(){

   return "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
}
```

Now, you need to add parameter to getImagePath function and and the functions should return the appropriate image url.

Comment: That is okay but the source is dynamically provided by mysql using php